# Play Framework: caching on templates

Tags: caching, playframework

I'm using Play Framework (v1.1.1) and I have a doubt about the #{cache} tag.

I suppose the question would be "when should I use it?" but I think it's quite generic.

So besides that, I would like to know if someone has checked its behaviour with Javascript. I understand that it will cache the output of other tags embedded in its body, but it will also cache Javascript? More specifically, if I include some script tags that reference external resources (like a CDN), the file will get cached too or only the tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the Cache tag is to cache the output that the server sends to the client. Javascript, images and any other information that is contained within the code sent to the client side is not cached, unless specifically told to do so by the headers set in the  tag of your HTML.

By default, Play (if you extend the main.html) does not specify any cache-control headers, so therefore your scripts will be cached based on the browsers standard caching policy. This should be "no-cache" according to the http spec, but I am doubtful of whether this is the case.

Comment: I suppose the output is cached server side? It's not cached client side via cache-control headers?

Comment: yes, server side. So an index page (for example) that is generated for 10,000 requests per hour for many different users (but the same content) can be cached (or parts of it) to reduce processing time in the template engine.